# ¿Cómo comparar dos strings en C++?

Tags: c++, string

Estoy realizado un programa estilo menú en el cual, la primera opción es "Añadir ciudad". El programa pide "Ingresa el nombre de la ciudad, pulsa 0 si no quieres añadir más: ". Mi problema viene aquí, no se como comparar la cadena de caracteres introducida con el número 0 para indicar que no quiero introducir más ciudades.

He probado con strcmp y su correspondiente librería stdio.h y string.h, pero me salta error. No se si es que lo estoy escribiendo mal o directamente no se hace así. El trozo de código al que me refiero es este:

```
if (strcmp(nombreCiudad, 0) == 0) {
    finalizar();
} else {
    seguirPidiendoNombres();
}
```

Comment: Sin poner los tipos de cada variable ... difícil será que alguien pueda ayudarte. Y si indicaras los errores **exactos** que obtienes y el código que lo genera, pues incluso mejor :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ¿Cómo comparar la cadena de caracteres introducida con el número 0 para indicar que no quiero introducir más ciudades?

Si estás guardando los datos en un `std::string`, basta con comparar con la cadena de caracteres `"0"`:

```
int main() {
    std::string ciudad;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, ciudad)) {
        if (ciudad == "0") // Es cero?
            return 0;  // Salir!

        std::cout << "La ciudad " << ciudad << " es muy bonita\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [TIO](https://tio.run/##RY09D4JADIbn669ozgUSTZgVnYyTs5NLPU6sgR65jxg1/nYEIXFp2udtn5quW9XG9P2CxTSpsliyC9FbanfwZwNhqXcALBFbYslyfIMKsVqvpwwNp4qqDYB63LixmP3C2saGxU6DYVnOe/nvXvEVswngdou60PkAlbcxecFilE0/jEsRyxL1kWYB6nGe@zFBG7BNT7w44Uhn0RtQn0Hwl336/mQlOt8OleDg/J1esCcvFEIKUMAX).

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

La función `strcmp` pertenece a las librerías de [c](/questions/tagged/c) y se usa para comparar formaciones<sup>1</sup> de caracteres. Si estás programando en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) deberías usar la cabecera `<string>` para trabajar con objetos de cadena de caracteres.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

Answer (score 1):

Hola si deseas comparar dos string en c podrias utilizar la funcion strcmp() lo podrias hacer haciendo algo asi:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char strg1[50], strg2[50];

    printf("Enter first string: ");
    gets(strg1);

    printf("confirmacion");
    gets(strg2);

    if(strcmp(strg1, strg2)==0)
    {
        printf("finalizar");
    }

    else

        //  si el valor es 0
        printf("hacer algo");
    }

    // signal to operating system program ran fine
    return 0;
}
```

[fuente](https://overiq.com/c-programming-101/the-strcmp-function-in-c/)

como vez en el codigo creo dos array para almacenar los dos valores(el numero 50 es basicamente el rango del array le puedes poner 2 o 3 )  y sobre el 0 que deseas comparar no necesario ingresarle ese valor porque si le ingresas 0 al programa , el compilador lo definira como NULL ,[mas info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140438/the-default-value-of-a-local-variable-in-c-is-a-garbage-value-right-then-why-am)

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: La persona que redactó la pregunta, dice explícitamente que su código es C++, no C.